# Flex-grow not proportionally adjusting width

Tags: css, flexbox, flex-grow

I'm just getting familiarized with Flex box and when i apply flex-grow:1 to a grouping of columns it seems to be making the column height grow equally but not the widths which is my goal.

If i'm understanding this, the default flex-direction is "row"...so in theory shouldn't the widths all be equal.

```
.flex{display:flex}
.flex div{flex-grow:1}

/*Just for visual separation*/
.flex div:nth-child(odd){background-color:#ccc}
```

Here is a Codepen of my example
http://codepen.io/dougmays/pen/dPWQdp

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you have in the codepen

This doesn't work

```
.flex{display:flex;}
.flex div{flex-grow:1}
```

but this does work

```
.flex2{display:flex;}
.flex2 div{flex:1}
```

The difference is that when you set flex:1 you also set flex-basis to 0px (the default).

In the first example, lacking a flex-basis value, the elements grow uniformly starting from their current width. Since this is different, the end result is also different

Comment: Awesome thank you! I actually google'd some more after this and found that Flex:1 works but didnt know the explanation. So in theory if i wanted to write more code This would also work:
flex-grow:1;
flex-basis:0px